# Cannot configure OLE DB connection manager using a sensitive parameter in SSIS 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I'm trying to make use of sensitive parameters in SQL Server Integration Services 2012 to configure my data source connections. I'm using OLE DB connections to a SQL Server 2012 database.

What I've found is that you cannot use a sensitive parameter to assign the connection string or the password property of the OLE DB connection manager. The connection string refuses to assign the value from the sensitive parameter.

The password property will take the parameter as a value for the expression but the connection doesn't actually work. I just get a "Login failed for Username" error so I assume it isn't actually assigning the password correctly. When I change the password parameter to not be sensitive the connection works correctly.

When assigning with the password parameter I have to assign all of the other connection properties (username, servername, initialcatalouge, and I have to set certain values in the connection string as well).

Is there a way to use sensitive parameters to configure my connection or is this just a limitation of the OLE DB connection manager?

I'd rather not encrypt the entire package because that means encrypting the entire solution. It is useful to be able to track changes in the XML using version control, which will be impossible if the entire solution is encrypted. However, it is important that the database connection information not be stored in plain-text.

The only other solution I can think of is to move the connection manager out of the package and make it a project-level connection. I've found that these retain all of their connection information without needing to be configured at run-time and keep the necessary parts encrypted. From looking at the XML it seems they are even sensitive fields.